# Switch NavigationController project to a Tabbar

Tags: iphone, navigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I know there are a multitude of questions regarding putting a navigation controller into a tabbar controller, but I want to change my navigation project to a tabbar project. I'm just not sure what exactly I need to change because I feel like I have to mess with some code and IB.

**In code:**

Is all I need to do is replace the navigationController with a tabBarController in my appDelegate

**In IB:**

Drag a tabBarController into my Objects and then do I drag my entire navigationController object into the tabBarController or just the RootViewController that is inside the navigationController?

Thanks for any advice on this. Normally, I would just give it a try but I feel like I could mess too much up.

Comment: I think it's best if you follow a good tutorial and start from first.

Comment: I've found tutorials on tabbars with navigation controllers but not switching from one to the other.

Comment: You want to replace your project with tabbarcontroller ? or do you want to have a tabbarcontroller inside a navigation controller ?

Comment: I currently have a Navigation-based Application and I now want it to be a TabBar Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an entirely new framework now as you want to shift from a `UINavigationController` to a `UITabBarController`. Just keep your view controllers as it is - you do not need to delete them.

1. Set the TabBarController as your `rootViewController`.
2. Use either the IB or code for creating them. If you use the IB, then open up a tabbarcontroller, and for each tabBarItem, assign the class to the different view controllers you had created. If you are doing this by code, I would suggest that you create an array of view controllers and add them to the TabBar.

   ```
   NSArray* viewControllerss = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: self, viewController1, viewController2, nil];

   NSLog(@"I am printing view controller array %@", viewControllerss);

   [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllerss animated:YES];
   ```

Comment: Adding the viewControllers via code was needed because I had to make some of the xibs via code.

Comment: Thanks again. Now I'm not able to set the tabBarItem title. I've tried setting self.title and self.navigationItem.title in the viewcontroller , and I've tried UITabBarItem *subgroupsItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"blah" image:nil tag:1];
    [tabBarController setTabBarItem:subgroupsItem]; Nothing works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hm. `self.title = @"My Title"` in the `viewDidLoad` should work.

Comment: Before adding the viewControllers to the the array , set `viewController1.title = @"1"; and viewController2.title = @"2";`